# Filtered lookup based on lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, filter

My situation is this: I'm trying to set up a review site for the publishing house I'm working for. Basically, the editors should be able to pick reviewers for new books based on certain categories. For instance, a new book on local breweries has the following categories attached: *Beer making*, *Local newspaper*, *Entrepreneurship*. Editors should then be able to choose reviewers based on these categories.

I have a list called *Categories* with a single column called *Category*, which in turn has a bunch of items, such as *Young Adults*, *Knitting*, *Local Newspaper*, etc.

I have a second list called *Reviewers* with basic columns such as *Name*, *Address*, etc., and a lookup column called *Categories*, linked to the *Category* column in the *Categories* list, allowing for multiple picks (which is to say, a reviewer can be attached to one or more categories).

I have also created a third list called *Reviews* with various related columns: 
*Book Title*, *Project Number*, *Date*: simple enough columns
*Categories*: A lookup column linked to the Category column in the Categories list, allowing for multiple picks.
*Reviewers*: The troublesome column. It should give the editors a filtered view of the reviewers based on the chosen categories, and of course allow them to pick said reviewers.

So my problem is getting the last (*Reviewers*) column to work. Is my solution a cascading lookup field, a calculated column, a workflow, some filter, or am I simply going about this the wrong way?

I've been working with SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer 2013 for less than two months, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. :)